# Can I require user assignment for my multi-tenanted Azure application?

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory

I am the primary developer on a multi-tenant SaaS web application hosted in Microsoft Azure. We use Azure AD for all authentication. Because our application holds personal information, we and our customers want a way to restrict access to specific users. We just need a simple yes/no restriction in place so only assigned users may access the application. We've considered Application Roles, but it seems like a lot of overhead when the only needed option is "authorized".

While researching this, I came across the following "User assignment required" property in Azure AD.
[User assignment required property in Azure Portal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OLFUw.png)

After some testing, I found that it functioned exactly as we need it to. The customer has full control over which users may access the application, and neither party has to configure Application Roles. The only downside is that this property is configured on the customer's end. Is there a way for me, as the developer, to require this setting? Or perhaps a way to enable this setting by default?

Clarification: The end-goal is minimal configuration done by the customer. If "User assignment required" can be enabled by the developers (before customer registration), that would be ideal.

Comment: I'm not very clear about what you're asking. What do you need to configure on the customer's end? `User assignment required` can be enable in AAD portal by the GA,not a user. Then only assigned users can access the application.

Comment: @WayneYang-MSFT I've updated the question to clarify the end-goal. I'm looking for a way to enable `User assignment required` for all future customers by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you cannot specify it in advance, it is up to the customer's administrator to set up the requirement.
This is their concern, not your application's concern.

One possible way would be to set `appRoleAssignmentRequired` on the created Service Principal to `true` via a Graph API call.
But that will require quite privileged access, with their admin logged in.

- [Service Principal entity reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference#serviceprincipal-entity)
- [Get SP by app Id](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/functions-and-actions#servicePrincipalsByAppId)

Comment: Um... After setting `appRoleAssignmentRequired`, only admin in the other tenant can access to the Multi-tenant app ?

Comment: Yes. And then they would need to assign who has access. In my opinion it also feels a bit pointless, since the admin might as well set user assignment required by themselves while assigning users.

Comment: @juunas I wasn't certain whose responsibility it should be. Thank you for your clear response. Bonus points for offering an alternative, but many of our customers won't consent to that level of control.